# jQuery: Fire function only when certain media query is true

Tags: jquery, media-queries

I have a jQuery function which should only be fired when a certain media query is true (both  on ready and resize).

I found a cool trick to check if a certain media query is true:

HTML

```
<div id="isthin"></div>
```

CSS

```
#isthin {
    display: inline-block;
    content: '';
    width: 1px;
    height: 1px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 1047px) {
    #isthin {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    if ( $('#isthin').is(":visible") ) {
        // function should be fired
    } else {
        // function should not be fired
    }
});

$(window).resize(function(){
    if ( $('#isthin').is(":visible") ) {
        // function should be fired
    } else {
        // function should not be fired
    }
});
```

Separate jQuery function

```
$(function () {
      $('nav li ul').hide().removeClass('sub-nav');
      $('nav li').hover(function () {
        $('ul', this).stop().slideToggle(300);
      });
});
```

That was my logic but somehow the function still runs on resizing when the media query changes.

Comment: Have you ever heard of [`matchmedia`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.matchMedia)?

Comment: Yes, but I have to support IE9 …

Comment: That's unfortunate...

Comment: Well you have a missing parenthesis, but once you add it, it work : http://jsfiddle.net/uLq5L/

Comment: Oh, I added the paranthesis. Your fiddle works but if I don’t override or stop the function it is somehow still executed …

Comment: I feel like there's some informations missing. What function do you override? What is your ultimate goal here?

Comment: See your updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/uLq5L/1/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55856/discussion-between-user1706680-and-karl-andre-gagnon).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The probleme is not the media query itself, but the way you are binding your event.

You're binding it on every resize when the query fits. You should really detach all your function and use a flag. Just like that :

```
var flag = true;

$(window).resize(function(){

    flag =  $('#isthin').is(":visible");

    if(flag){
        $('nav li ul').hide().removeClass('sub-nav');
    }else{
        $('nav li ul').show().addClass('sub-nav');
    }

})

$(document).ready(function(){

    $(window).trigger('resize');
})

$(function () {
    $('nav li').hover(function () {
        if(flag){
            $('ul', this).stop().slideToggle(300);
        }
    });
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uLq5L/3/)

Answer (score 2):

Based on your snippets, I have this script opened with a browser:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
    <style type="text/css">
    #isthin {
      display: inline-block;
      content: '';
      width: 1px;
      height: 1px;
      overflow: hidden;
      border: 1px solid red;
   }
   @media only screen and (max-width: 1047px) {
      #isthin {
        display: none;
      }
  }
  </style>

  <script type="text/javascript">    
    $(document).ready(function(){
      if ( $('#isthin').is(":visible") ) {
        // function should be fired
        console.log("[doc ready] Media Query wide");
      } else {
        // function should not be fired
        console.log("[doc ready] Media Query thin");
      }
   });

   $(window).resize(function(){
     if ( $('#isthin').is(":visible") ) {
        // function should be fired
        console.log("[Resize] Media Query wide");
     } else {
        // function should not be fired
        console.log("[Resize] Media Query thin");
     }
   });
</script>
</head>
  <body>
    <div id="isthin"><id>
  </body>
</html>
```

If I pull the browser narrow and wide again, I see the console messages as they should be:

```
[doc ready] Media Query wide 
[Resize] Media Query wide 
[Resize] Media Query wide 
[Resize] Media Query wide 
[Resize] Media Query wide 
...
...
[Resize] Media Query thin 
[Resize] Media Query thin 
[Resize] Media Query thin 
[Resize] Media Query thin 
...
[Resize] Media Query wide
...
...
```

Therefore, I think your way of detecting a media query is correct (and sophisticated). I suggest you check:

- if it's a browser specific problem,
- how your separate jQuery function is linked to the resize callback.

Then, consider that in this case you don't save some work by using CSS queries. You need the resize callback anyway. So watch this other elegant way I've seen to solve this problem. It's the other way round, avoiding CSS selectors but doing the same:

```
$(window).resize(function(){
    if ( $(window).width() < xxxx && $(window).width() > yyyyy ) {

        $('body').addClass('phone');  // <<<<<<<<<<<<<<
        $('body').removeClass('tablet');
        $('body').removeClass('workstation');

    } else if ( ... ) {

        $('body').removeClass('phone');
        $('body').addClass('tablet');  // <<<<<<<<<<<<<<
        $('body').removeClass('workstation');

    } 
    ...
    ...
}
```

Then you can easy distinguish in CSS by adding .phone, .tablet and .workstation to the selectors and can possibly remove the queries. Further:

```
$(window).resize(function(){
    if ($('body').hasClass('phone')) {

       ...
       ...

    } else if ( ... ) {
       ...
    } 
    ...
    ...
}
```

Like this, you have it all on the JS side and less on the CSS side.

The idea is not by me, I saw it in a framework but I'm not sure wich one it was.